# ASP.NET C# - A function with arguments to write dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and C#.

What I am trying to do is some type of function where I can feed some argumennts, which will generate a dropdown list box for me.  I know ASP.NET is much better, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish similar or even better.

When I've done before with classic ASP/VBScript was I have a Sub routine to generate a dropdown list.
Example:

```
Sub CreateSelectBox(selectboxID, onChangeTrigger, selectedValue, SQLTable, and SQLCondition)
     ' ... Query the databse from SQLTable, write a SelectBox with option values, and selected the selectedValue for arguments....
End Sub
```

So, all I have to do in the any submit form is just one line of code. like this:

```
<tr><td><%CreateSelectBox "DropDownList1", "onChangeRunJavascript123();", "Selected123", "SQL_CustomerTable", "where CustomerType = 'Consumer' order by SortOrder ASC" %></td></tr>
```

Please advise a better way to do this in ASP.Net C#, please provide a code sample if possible since I am new.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Web Forms (http://www.asp.net/web-forms),  ASP.NET MVC (http://www.asp.net/mvc) or ASP.NET Web Pages (http://www.asp.net/web-pages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.net has a [DropdownList control that helps to do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [this is very old tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210610092904/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071101-1.shtml) and [Databound Controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-bound-controls)

Markup: .aspx file

```
<asp:DropdownList runat="server" ID="MyList" DataTextField="PersonName" DataValueField="PersonID">

</asp:DropdownList>
```

CodeBehind: .aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       MyList.DataSource = getDataFromDB();
       MyList.DataBind();
   }
}


//this function can return IEnumerable e.g. DataTable of Person, List<Person>, SqlDataReader etc
private DataTable getDataFromDB()
{
   //select data from database
   //return data;
}
```

Comment: +1. I'd also suggest that Milacay reads up on data bound controls in general - that syntax suggests a background in ASP or Php :)

Comment: Yes I agree. I couldn't find a tutorial that's simple

Comment: Sam's Teach Yourself ASP.Net in ...?